# Get images from directory 

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get all images from a directory in WP7. I already use

```
var temp = Directory.GetFiles(@"\Pictures");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

by the way i also tried the isolated storage solution. but none of those solution seems to work.
Is i a wp7 limitation?

Comment: `Isolated Store` or `Application Content`? Try `/Pictures`, `Pictures/` or `/Pictures/`. I haven't VS to check right path now. Also install `Windows Phone Power Tools` to check that images are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoud use following code for images from the resources:

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative);

            String originalUriString = uri.OriginalString;
            Uri resourceStreamUri = originalUriString.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? new Uri(originalUriString.TrimStart('/'), UriKind.Relative) : uri;
            StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceStreamUri);

            if (null != streamResourceInfo)
            {
                stream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;

                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should use [IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02ys433.aspx) instead.

Good tutorial: [How to: Find Existing Files and Directories in Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd5e2z84.aspx)

Comment: I do not use the isolatedStorage. I just use a fix list of image in my application. My complete source is "Solution->Pictures->myImage.jpg". Those images are available when I use them in my background for example. But when I want to be dynamic it doesn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

You probalby have your pictures as Resource and not as Content. Right click on images in your solution and change the Build Action to Content.

Comment: I change it but i still have an error : This exception typically occurs when the caller does not have access permission to the member.